# Java Regex Doesn't Work For Characters As Like \n

Tags: java, regex

I want to remove all characters that starts with `{{` and ends with `}}` I've written that regex:

```
String templatePattern = "\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}";
```

and I use that:

```
text.replaceAll(templatePattern, "");
```

It works but for strings as like that:

```
{{Apple \n banana }}
```

it doesn't work. If I replace all `\n` characters with space character it works. What is the proper solution for it? Because I should apply same thing for `\t` and others too.

Comment: You have to escape the escape character. Try using \\n and \\t instead.

Comment: `.` doesn't match newlines by default.

Comment: @KevinWorkman should I apply it for every combination?

Comment: Try `String templatePattern = "(?s)\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}";`

Answer (score 6):

The reason is, a `dot` matches anything but `\n`. If you want to match everything, then you can use `[\s\S]`, or `[\w\W]` or any such variations of complimenting meta-characters:

```
String templatePattern = "\\{\\{[\s\S]*?\\}\\}";
```

Another way is to make the `dot` actually match the newline, by using `(?s)` flag:

```
String templatePattern = "(?s)\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}";
```

The later one is indeed a better way. `(?s)` is same as `Pattern.DOTALL`.

Comment: No need for this JavaScript-"inspired" hack. Use `Pattern.DOTALL` or the inline `(?s)` modifier.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yup, was updating :)